# How to Parcelable a Java Bean like below?

Tags: android, parcelable, android-databinding

```
public class FoodBean {
    public final ObservableField<String> description = new ObservableField<>();
    public final ObservableField<String> image = new ObservableField<>();
    public final ObservableField<String> keywords = new ObservableField<>();
    public final ObservableField<String> summary = new ObservableField<>();
}
```

All member variables should be defined `final` in this bean, so how to parcelable this class?

Comment: What have you done thus far to solve the problem?

Comment: I use Serializable instead as Parcelable constructor will assign the variables  which is defined final. But you know final  variable can not be assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Serializable instead. As we know from the Android api, ObservableField variables must be declared final. But Parcelable constructor will assign the variables. so it causes conflict as final variables can not be assigned any more.